# How to remove a specific job from Redis job queue

Tags: redis

I'm new to Redis so this will be a rudimentary question.

I'm considering creating a Redis job queue using a list. The jobs themselves will be JSON-encoded objects.

I realize that I can use `LPOP` and `RPUSH` for managing the queue. I can even use [`RPOPLPUSH`](http://redis.io/commands/rpoplpush) when using multiple lists (e.g "Queued", "Processing" and "Completed").

Let's say I have a worker that processes images by steadily going through the "Queued" list. Then let's say the client has deleted an image from the front-end, before that particular job has even begun to process. How do I delete this job from the "Queued" list so the worker doesn't waste time processing it?

In other words, how can I index individual jobs in a job queue?

Answer (score 0):

use a sorted set with the timestamp as the score and you can remove a job

```
$ redis-cli zadd myjobs `date +"%s.%N"` job1
$ redis-cli zadd myjobs `date +"%s.%N"` job2
$ redis-cli zadd myjobs `date +"%s.%N"` job3
$ redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379> ZRANGEBYSCORE myjobs -inf +inf WITHSCORES
1) "job1"
2) "1638908693.1293526"
3) "job2"
4) "1638908696.5061705"
5) "job3"
6) "1638908699.2742543"
127.0.0.1:6379> ZREMRANGEBYLEX myjobs [job2 [job2
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> ZRANGEBYSCORE myjobs -inf +inf WITHSCORES
1) "job1"
2) "1638908693.1293526"
3) "job3"
4) "1638908699.2742543"
```